# Пример Upload file на TypeScript (без Angular)

Tags: typescript, fileupload

Господа,

я некоторое время назад начал писать первый проект на TypeScript.
Проект - это single page application, что то типа ToDo List.

Сейчас я сделал, что пункты в лист добавляются.
Но хочу сделать загрузку файлов (например, изображений и текстовых файлов, которые будут обрабатываться при загрузке)

Не могу найти никакого примера upload file на TypeScript.
Нашел пример, который делает намного больше - добавляет несколько файлов, показывает прогресс аплоада и какую то статистику - но он сложный, и я не смог в нём разобраться. ( [Сложный пример аплоада файлов](https://www.igniteui.com/file-upload/typescript) )

Не поможет ли кто с таким же, но простым примером?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

смотря как вы хотите грузить файл: HTML5 file upload или формой.
я не вижу проблем транслировать код этих методов с JS (где примеров множество) на Typescript.

Comment: Я хочу в HTML написать что то вроде 
прикрепить файл: <input id="file1" type="file"/>
Потом я ниже римую кнопку, и на её обработчик вешаю функцию, которая уже в TypeScript.
Это всё получается безх проблем. А вот дальше - проблема: 
В ТуреЫскшзе - коде я делаю что то вроде 
var file1Field = document.getElementById("file1");
Это - поле, которео было предназначено для ввода файла.
а как из него получить сам файл?

Comment: нужно ли перезагружать страницу или загружать ajax?

Comment: Я собираюсь всё делать Ajax'ом, и я даже понимаю примерно, как:
 var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("eid", a.Eid);
  formData.append("textField", txt);
  formData.append("file1", files[0]);

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  try {
    xhr.open('POST', "AcceptForm.aspx", false);
    xhr.send(formData);
  }
  catch (error) {
    var ec = error.code;
    var rt = xhr.responseText;
    return;
  }
Вот только как создать массив files[] или хотя бы полкчить его эелмент files[0] - не знаю :-(

Comment: Я читаю пример на JS, в нём получение файла просиходит так:
var selectedFile = document.getElementById('input').files[0]; Но я не могу напрямую транслировать эту конструкцию в TypeScript. Последний вызов в цепочке (.file[0]) - не работает :-(

Comment: тут нужно прямо указать тип, который ожидается после получения по ID.

let input = <HTMLInputElement> document.getElementById('input');
input.files[0]

почитайте тут как type assertion работает.
https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-assertion.html